Understanding sigaction structure using GDB
I want to better understand sigaction and I have reached this instruction using gdb.
0x73xxxxxxxx:    bl  0x73xxxxxxxx <sigaction@plt>
If I were to explore its parameters,
x0             0x0e                14
x1             0x7fxxxxxxxx        xxxxxxxxxxxx
x2             0x0


x0 should be referring to the signal to handle?
x1 should be the new sigaction structure?
x2 should be the old sigaction structure (so this means there is
no old sigaction structure defined?)

If I explore x1 further,
(gdb) x/16gx 0x7fxxxxxxxx
0x7fe5xxxxc0:   0x0000000000000004  0x0000007365xxxxxx
0x7fe5xxxxd0:   0xffffffffffffffff  0x0000000000000000
0x7fe5xxxxe0:   0x0000000000000020  0x0000003800030015
0x7fe5xxxxf0:   0x0000003800020015  0x0000003800010015
0x7fe5xxxx00:   0x000000380f000015  0x0000000c00000020
0x7fe5xxxx10:   0x0000007300020015  0x0000007304000025
0x7fe5xxxx20:   0x000000730b030025  0x0000000800000020

What do each of the qword mean? I know the second qword (0x7365xxxxxx) should be referring to the handler function for the signal but how do I map the rest of the qwords to the sigaction structure?


how do I map the rest of the qwords to the sigaction structure?

You look in whatever header defines struct sigaction.
Using echo "#include <signal.h>" | gcc -xc - -E can help you find that header and the definition.
On my system, that's /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigaction.h and it contains:
struct sigaction
  {
    union
      {
        __sighandler_t sa_handler;
        void (*sa_sigaction) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);
      }
    __sigaction_handler;
    __sigset_t sa_mask;
    int sa_flags;
    void (*sa_restorer) (void);
  };

But on your system this would be different (perhaps sa_flags are before sa_handler).
Update:

Is there a GDB command that lets me cast the memory address to the struct layout for sigaction?

Yes: you simply cast it like so:
(gdb) print *(struct sigaction *) 0x7fxxxxxxxx

If GDB doesn't know what struct sigaction is, you can tell it.

I searched online that sigset_t is 128 bytes large,

Searching online is the wrong answer. You should just look in the gcc -E output I already mentioned. On my system, __sitset_t is:
typedef struct
{
  unsigned long int __val[(1024 / (8 * sizeof (unsigned long int)))];
} __sigset_t;

That's 1024 / 8 == 128.

does that mean I have to count 16 by 8 qwords in order to map that to sigset_t?

Yes.

Hi @Employed Russian
Is there a GDB command that lets me cast the memory address to the struct layout for sigaction?
Furthermore I searched online that sigset_t is 128 bytes large, does that mean I have to count 16 by 8 qwords in order to map that to sigset_t?

@localacct I've updated the answer. P.S. you should avoid asking new question(s) in a comment -- just ask a new question.

Hi @Employed Russian
Thanks for the answer. Sorry for asking questions in the comments.
